# For pushing a rails app to Heroku, what is the correct way to configure my databases in config/database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to push my Rails app to Heroku and running into difficulty.

In the `config/database.yml` file I've seen examples like this, where the database name is prefixed with 'db/':

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/the_business_casual_pro
```

As well as examples like this, without the prefix:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: FullstackProject_development
```

Is one way preferred over the other, or is one an older way of doing it?

Right now my database.yml file is just this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/the_business_casual_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/the_business_casual_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/the_business_casual_pro
```

I've seen the code below in a previous project but am unsure what I'd need to do first to add these lines.

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: FullstackProject_production
  username: FullstackProject
  password: <%= ENV['FULLSTACKPROJECT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Any insights very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the full `config/database.yml` file?

Comment: @moritzg I edited the post to show what's in my config/database.yml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you locally develop a Rails application you're not using a Postgres instance for development, but a SQLite database. Rails stores these databases in a folder called `db`. You can actually check the `db` for your project if there are any files in it.

With Heroku, you're using a Postgres instance and you're defining the database in another way.

So I would keep the `db/` for development (including the SQLite adapter) and for production you probably want to use `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` as Heroku [suggests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior) it.